# Overflow with LineWithFocusChart when interpolating nvd3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a problem with the LineWithFocusChart. Whenever I use interpolate('cardinal') the graph-line is cut at the border of the graph. How can I add some kind of padding or enable the graph to draw outside its borders?
[image: image of the chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It is possible with clipEdge set to false:

```
chart.clipEdge(false)
```